# How would I go about sending captcha from my program to Captcha Sniper and then receiving the output? Surely it's possible

Tags: vb.net

Im using Visual Basic 2012 which I want to send a Captcha image from my picture box to CaptchaSniper. Can it be done?

Comment: Please show [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: ive been given this code:

Comment: With New Net.WebClient
    Try
        Dim b() As Byte = .UploadFile(New System.Uri("127.0.0.1"), Captcha.Path)
        Captcha.Solution = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b).Split(CChar("|"))(5).ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Result.FailMessage = "Could not retrieve captcha response; " & ex.Message
        Exit Try
    End Try
End With

Comment: Ok? And what is the problem with that code? Do you get an exception, or does it not give you the result you want?

Comment: does not give the result i wanted. at "captch.path" i was tolt to declear a string with the path of the captcha destination